# How to release a AVAudioPlayer object when it has to play a short sound every second after pressing a button

Tags: ios4, audio, avaudioplayer, autorelease

I have the following problem making me crazy.
My app has to play a tick sound every second for a specified number of times (e.g. 5) after the user has pressed a button.

I used this:


`for (int w=1; w<=5; w++) {

    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(tic) toTarget:self withObject:nil];

    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.0];

}`

where:

`- (void)tic {

 NSAutoreleasePool *ticPool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

 player_tic = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"tick" ofType:@"aif"]] error:nil];

 [player_tic setDelegate:self];

 [player_tic play];

 [ticPool drain];

}`

and:

`- (void) audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying: (AVAudioPlayer *)player_tic successfully:(BOOL)flag {

 NSLog(@"Audio finished playing.");

 [player_tic release];

}`

All seems to work. My problem is that the object are released together at the end.
I need that after **every** played sound the related 'player_tic' has to be released immediately.

Other Info:

In .m:

`@synthesize player_tic;`

In .h:

`@interface myController : UIViewController {

...

AVAudioPlayer *player_tic;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) AVAudioPlayer *player_tic;`

On top of all, I have this warning in compilation:

`local declaration of 'player_tic' hides instance variable`

Please help me!
Thank you very much in advance.

--Carlo

Answer (score 0):

I found [System Sound Services](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/SystemSoundServicesReference/Reference/reference.html) more responsive than AVAudioPlayer.

It also solves your release problem, which is caused by the retain property of your controller. Read the reference manual on memory management for further information on retain/release.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. But I would like to avoid System Sounds cause their volume is 'ringtone-related' and not 'application related'. Could I change something in my code to work properly with AVAudioPlayer?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use self.player_tic when setting that variable, and i believe you also want to autorelease that instance. I'm not sure that setting up a separate NSAutoreleasePool is necessary either.

```
self.player_tic = [[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:... error:nil] autorelease]
```

Comment: Unfortunately using 'autorelease' any sound is reproduced. Thank you for your comment anyway.

Comment: then you can set a callback for when the AVAudioPlayer is finished, and set self.player_tic = nil then.